# Displaying Date In A User Formated Style with php

Tags: php, mysql

I've noticed that Facebook, Twitter, and lots of other sites are using a relative date and time string description for user posts and comments.

For example, "comment written about 3 months ago" instead of "comment written on September 20, 2012." I decided to do the same thing on my site. In my site I need to display 1 day ago, 2 days ago, 3 days ago,...... 1 week ago, 2 weeks ago, .... 1 months ago, 2 months ago, ...... 1 year ago, 2 years ago... etc.

Already I have got user registered date and need to check it with current date and time and need to diplay it with above style on my home page.

In my database, user registered date format is like this ..  '2012-09-23 09:11:02'

can anybody help me to build this script in php... and it will greatly appriciated.

Thank you.

Comment: you should try yourself first,believe me its not tough

Comment: You'll do better on StackOverflow if you take a stab at this yourself first. Then, if you run into troubles, come back here with specific questions :)

I will give you a hint though: read up on the date() and strtotime() functions.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code,

```
function time_elapsed_since ($postedDateTime){

    $time = time() - $postedDateTime; // to get the time since that moment

         $tokens = array (
                      31536000 => 'year',
                      2592000 => 'month',
                      604800 => 'week',
                      86400 => 'day',
                      3600 => 'hour',
                      60 => 'minute',
                      1 => 'second'
                  );

                  foreach ($tokens as $unit => $text) {
                      if ($time < $unit) continue;
                      $numberOfUnits = floor($time / $unit);
                      return $numberOfUnits.' '.$text.(($numberOfUnits>1)?'s':'');
                  }

    }
```

Usage:

```
time_elapsed_since($postedDateTime).' ago'; // 2012-09-23 09:11:02 format
```

Comment: I dnt like people supporting spoon feeding

Comment: Its work for weeks and months. but not working for seconds, minutes and hours. suppose I added a profile just now it is not displaying 1 second ago, 2 seconds ago... etc and 1 minute ago, 2 minutes ago.. etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this

```
function time_ago($time) {

   $periods = array("second", "minute", "hour", "day", "week", "month", "year", "decade");
   $lengths = array("60","60","24","7","4.35","12","10");

   $now = time();

   $difference = $now - $time;
   $tense = "ago";

   for($j = 0; $difference >= $lengths[$j] && $j < count($lengths)-1; $j++) {
        $difference /= $lengths[$j];
   }

   $difference = round($difference);

   if($difference != 1) {
        $periods[$j].= "s";
   }

   return "$difference $periods[$j] 'ago' ";
}
```

Comment: Its work for weeks and months. but not working for seconds, minutes and hours. suppose I added a profile just now it is not displaying 1 second ago, 2 seconds ago... etc and 1 minute ago, 2 minutes ago.. etc.

Comment: @thara: can you do any stuff by your self?

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing they are using unixtime ie the number of seconds since 1970 (which is standard). I suggest that should also keep your dates in that format. If they are using unix time you can use the following date function in PHP to convert it to your format above:

```
<?php
date('Y-m-t H:i:s', $facebookTime);
```

Regards,
Kevin